# How do I cut text through an object?

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing

I am making scoreboard to 3d print and want the "Player 1   Player 2" to be a window for a light behind it. I tried the knife project and also a boolean with no luck. Can anyone help me out here?I want to cut the lettering all the way through.[image] Thanks

[image]

Comment: Both knife project and boolean operations are working here for me with your example file. Boolean operations need volume to work, [search this site for boolean](http://blender.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=boolean) and you will see tons and tons of questions with solutions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a solid 3D mesh out of the Text to get the Boolean Modifier working.

Select the text mesh and drag it up (z axis) a little. Use a solidify modifier and adjust its thickness until the text mesh goes through the Scoreboard mesh (you don't need to apply it).

Select the Scoreboard mesh, add a Boolean Modifier, select "Difference" as operation and "Text" as the object to use for the modifier.

Here's the .blend file with unapplied modifiers:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to use Knife Project.

1. Created the text.
2. Convert it to a mesh.
3. Move it in place above the object you want to cut through.
4. Select the text, add the object to the selection.
5. Switch to edit mode, select all, then use Knife Project from the
   toolbar.
6. Make sure you check the *Cut Through* option (you will need a reasonably recent version of Blender for this option).
7. Then it's just a matter of connecting the dots.

Connecting the dot can be a bit tedious, but you usually get a cleaner mesh than that using a boolean.  See the partially completed example below.

[image]